Renaming relational tables on existing schema in Django
Due to a migration from django 2.x to django 4.x, I had to rename my project to fix the intial name containing '-' and no '_'.

The initial project name was DEMANDE-PROJET
In a Model called DEMANDE ( DEMANDE-PROJET_DEMANDE ), I have a foreign key ( field created_by ) to a model called UserDemandeMapper 
created_by = models.ForeignKey('UserDemandeMapper', related_name="demande_createur",
                                   on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)


Django is handling this table on its own and on my DB browser I can see it on the name DEMANDE-PROJET_USERDEMANDE2573

Now I renamed my project, django want to request DEMANDE_PROJET_* instead of DEMANDE-PROJET_*

I couldn't request anything anymore.
I added :
    class Meta:
        db_table = "DEMANDE-PROJET_DEMANDE"

to link my django model to the tables that gets a fixed name. And now I can request Demande without any problem.

The problem comes from my created_by foreign key. I have the value of the ID but not the Model Object of the foreign model.

I tried to add UserDemandeMapper a meta class with a db_name but nothing worked.

As I'm not a migration expert and this side of django is a bit nebulous, I would like help on it.


I tried to add UserDemandeMapper a meta class with a db_name but
nothing worked.

If this is not a typo in your question, I suggest trying db_table instead of db_name just like you did for you other class:
class UserDemandeMapper(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = "DEMANDE-PROJET_USERDEMANDEMAPPER" 


Thanks @Luci !
I tried db_table also, tried the managed parameter, but it still does not link to my table from Django ...
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ....
